# Add DTD when serializing with Jackson XmlMapper

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

When I serialize my POJO everything works as expected. I get something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gsafeed>
   ...
</gsafeed>
```

The recipient (Google Search Appliance) seems to expect that the XML contains a DTD like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE gsafeed PUBLIC "-//Google//DTD GSA Feeds//EN" "">
<gsafeed>
   ...
</gsafeed>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Since there seems to be no elegant solution anyway, I went for prepending the required `<!DOCTYPE` (and the `<?xml`) to the output string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per other answers, there is unfortunately no way to achieve this in a simple way.

One thing that might be helpful for long term is filing a request for adding such a feature -- it sounds like a reasonable feature to expose via XML-specific `ObjectWriter`, for example.

Comment: A little bit unsatisfying since it does not seem to be an exotic requirement. I followed your suggestion to file a request.

Comment: To me it does seem like an exotic requirement, never having needed this, nor having seen any requests to that. But I am not saying it is an unreasonable feature request or anything like that. Just not a common need based on my experiences.

Comment: No offense! Maybe I had a wrong impression since this was one of the first occasions I used it... (feeding to a Google Search Appliance, which seems to be picky about that).

Answer (score 1):

I usually despise answers to Jackson questions that are "write a custom serializer" because usually there is a simpler, cleaner way. Unfortunately, I don't know a better way to achieve adding metadata to serialized output other then a custom serializer.

Hopefully somebody responds with a simpler solution, but this should accomplish what you are trying to achieve.

#### Create a module to house the custom serializer

```java
public class GsaFeedModule extends SimpleModule {
    private static final String NAME = "GsaFeedModule";

    public GsaFeedModule() {
        super(NAME);
        addSerializer(GsaFeed.class, new GsaFeedSerializer());
    }

    public static class GsaFeedSerializer extends JsonSerializer<GsaFeed> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(GsaFeed gsaFeed, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            jsonGenerator.writeRaw("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
            jsonGenerator.writeRaw("<!DOCTYPE gsafeed PUBLIC \"-//Google//DTD GSA Feeds//EN\" \"\">");
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
            // write fields
            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Register the module

```java
XmlMapper xm = new XmlMapper();
xm.registerModule(new GsaFeedModule());
```

Comment: The downside of this solution is that it will only apply to the `GsaFeed` object, and also requires defining all fields (which can get verbose).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no an elegant way for setting DTD. Apart of implementing a custom serializer you can consider overriding the `XmlSerializerProvider` to write the DTD string write after the initialization of the XML generator. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonXmlDTD {
    private static class DtdXmlSerializerProvider extends XmlSerializerProvider {
        private final String dtd;

        public DtdXmlSerializerProvider(
                final XmlSerializerProvider src,
                final SerializationConfig config,
                final SerializerFactory jsf,
                final String dtd) {
            super(src, config, jsf);
            this.dtd = dtd;
        }

        @Override
        protected void _initWithRootName(final ToXmlGenerator xgen, final QName rootName)
                throws IOException {
            super._initWithRootName(xgen, rootName);
            try {
                xgen.getStaxWriter().writeDTD(dtd);
            } catch (final XMLStreamException e) {
                StaxUtil.throwXmlAsIOException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public DefaultSerializerProvider createInstance(
                final SerializationConfig config, final SerializerFactory jsf) {
            return new DtdXmlSerializerProvider(this, config, jsf, dtd);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.enable(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION);
        final String dtd = "<!DOCTYPE gsafeed PUBLIC \"-//Google//DTD GSA Feeds//EN\" \"\">";
        final DtdXmlSerializerProvider serializerProvider = new DtdXmlSerializerProvider(
                (XmlSerializerProvider) xmlMapper.getSerializerProvider(),
                xmlMapper.getSerializationConfig(),
                xmlMapper.getSerializerFactory(),
                dtd);
        xmlMapper.setSerializerProvider(serializerProvider);
        final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("object", "value");
        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(map));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE gsafeed PUBLIC "-//Google//DTD GSA Feeds//EN" ""><HashMap xmlns=""><object>value</object></HashMap>
```