# Easy way to add DOCTYPE to XML with Jackson

Tags: xml, java-8, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

My XML document needs to have `DOCTYPE` definition.
I use the following APIs/frameworks:

- Java 8
- Jackson for XML

Gradle's dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Serializer:

```
 public String createXMLDoc(Object request){
        XmlMapper xmlMapper =  new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);//XML declaration

        try {
            return xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(request);
        }
        catch(JsonProcessingException e){
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Is there a way to add the DOCTYPE as ease as this, e.g.,:

```
xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
```

which is XML doc declaration.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845416/add-dtd-when-serializing-with-jackson-xmlmapper

Comment: Yeap, but I have been expecting something similar to the above example.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I have simply prefixed the DOCTYPE declaration, as part of String concatenation.