# Jackson generates xml without the <?xml?> tag at the top

Tags: java, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a Java app that uses Jackson to generate a xml, but the final xml doesn't have the `<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "yes"?>` at the beginig of the document, it starts at the `<source>` tag.

I need this  tag to appear at the top, but I can't manage to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using XmlMapper you can add 'WRITE_XML_DECLARATION' configuration to add it

```
    XmlMapper xmlMapper =  new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);//XML declaration
```

See, this question - [Easy way to add DOCTYPE to XML with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594320/easy-way-to-add-doctype-to-xml-with-jackson)

Comment: Why didn't you just mark the question as a dupe?

Comment: @RuanMendes probably because "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer". The solution Vini provided comes from the question's body

Comment: So why point to it?

Comment: Point noted @Ruan Mendes. I pointed to the other question as it is slightly different - there the OP wants to add the DOCTYPE declaration but just mentions that he has the Xml declaration in place.