# Jackson XML: Custom Tag line

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, objectmapper

I'm working with Jackson XML to covert JSON data into formatted xml output. So far, I have been able to convert the JSON data to java objects, which then are parsed to an XML output.

I'm trying to add a separate line to this xml (similar to adding ) but not sure how. Hoping the output for the xml comes out like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--DOCTYPE ... -->
```

Is there a way to add this tag before my actual generated xml tags?

Comment: Similar question: [Add DTD when serializing with Jackson XmlMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845416/add-dtd-when-serializing-with-jackson-xmlmapper)

Comment: I guess there's no solution in Jackson yet. But thank you!